# Get list of Directories and Files from Windows Azure File Storage using File Service REST API

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, azure-storage

I am trying to get list of directories and files for given path from Azure File Storage. I want to call Azure File Storage REST APIs via JQUERY AJAX call.

Here is the link to get list of directories and files from azure file storage
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/azure/dn166980.aspx

I am stuck in request header part which is not clearly explained.

It will be a great help for me if someone can help me getting information using jquery ajax call.

Comment: What is not clear about the header part? Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft, I have tried this jquery code, function getDir(parentDirName) {        
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://mystorage.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/"+ parentDirName +"?restype=directory&comp=list",
            type: "GET"
        })
        .success(function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                
            }
            else {
                
            }
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) { });
    }          I am not sure how to pass authorization value in request header of this jquery ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to construct and pass the Authorization header as outlined in the official Azure Storage documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/azure/dd179428.aspx in order to get the response you're looking for. If you're looking for help on how to add headers to AJAX, unrelated to storage, you're probably looking for something like:

`beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authorizationToken);
            },`

which can be found elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can also take a look at our official node.js library which might give you some pointers on how to construct the header in a JS context: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node